# Error in converting values in the field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I would like to calculate the flux of water in a river system.
The flux is given in km<sup>3</sup>/year and I would like to convert it to m<sup>3</sup>/month. My syntax is:

```
"flux"*1000000000/12
```

If I execute this the following error is shown:

> An error occurred during the evaluation of the calculation expression:
>   Can not convert ',' to floating-point number.

The same error I keep getting if the `to_real` function is running.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: @JochenSchwarze: I used only the replace syntax. If you create a new field you can choose an other type of fields. Thanks a lot. The bachelor thesis is saved!

Answer (score 4):

The error message indicates that `"flux"` is of type `text` and needs to be converted to a `float` number to do the required calculations (it furthermore indicates, that QGIS does such conversion implicitly, provided the string has the correct format).

To be precise, the correct decimal is ".", and in your case obviously is ",".

Thus, with the above observation deviating from my comment you just need to do you calculation on a string with "," replaced by "." like

```
replace("flux", ',', '.') * 1000000000.0 / 12.0
```

This of course can be confusing, since the operator "*" can have different meanings depending on the resulting data type, e.g.:

- result data type `float`: `'10.3' * 3 = 30.9` in QGIS expression builder
- result data type `string`: `'10.3' * 3 = '30.9'` in QGIS expression builder
- result data type `string`: `'10.3' * 3 = '10.310.310.3'` as in Python (allways evaluated to `string`)

Thus, the clearer form would be

```
to_real(replace("flux", ',', '.')) * 1000000000.0 / 12.0
```

because this explicitly multiplies `real` by `real`.

Comment: what's the difference between the first and second example?

Comment: the resulting data type.

Comment: Oh, I see where you are coming from. It's not actually, that it's the result of `*` is different but rather that the (float) result is autoconverted to a string. E.g. having `3.3` saved to a string field will also result in `'3.3'` without any `*` involved. In short `*` in expressions will always try to convert the two involved values to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the **Refactor Fields** algorithm and check the field type. If it's for example the `string` then change it to an `integer` and run the tool. At least in my case, it worked.